# Find Orthonormal Basis for Image Plane Given Camera Matrix

Tags: geometry

Given a projection matrix $P = [M | p_4]$, ($M \in 3 \times 3$, $p_4 \in 3 \times 1 $), the principal axis (the vector that passes through the center of projection and is perpendicular  to the image plane) $v$  is $$v = det(M)m_3$$ where $m_3$ is the third row of $M$. Is this correct?

Now I want to find two more vectors, say $v_1$ and $v_2$, that form an orthonormal basis with $v$ and span the image plane. I know that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not unique so I want them to be equal to the $x$- and $y$-axes once the principal axis coincides with the $z$-axis (of some world coordinate system). If the principal axis differs from the $z$-axis due to some transformation I want that same transformation to give me $v_1$ and $v_2$ if applied to the $x$- and $y$-axes. Hope you get what I mean by that!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your requirement still does not force a unique representation: you can rotate about the $z$ axis while maintaining alignment of that axis with your principal axis. As a consequence, “that same transformation” isn't well defined. Basically you want two more vectors orthogonal to $m_3$, right? Simply compute the cross product between that axis and *any* vector, and the result will be orthogonal. If may be zero, so take the cross product with the three unit vectors and choose the result with maximal length as $v_1$. You can then compute $v_2=m_3\times v_1$.

Comment: Hmmmmm i see :( ... what if I know the extrinsic parameters of my camera? Doesn't that give me that transformation?